# Is it possible to reach The Lighthouse in Destiny only by buying Favors of Osiris?

Tags: destiny

Trials of Osiris in Destiny is a special PVP playlist. 3 losses and you're done, but as you win more the rewards significantly increase. At 9 wins and 0 losses you're able to enter a special social area that has additional rewards. This is easier said than done.

The associated vendor offers an item that "adds one win to your trials passage". If I purchase enough of these (9), will I be able to reach The Lighthouse?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I thought you could only buy one per try (once you buy one, you can't buy another until you lose 3 or win 9)

Comment: That's what I heard, but I've *heard* whispers that you can buy 9. I'd prefer not to wastes my coins, so I figured I would ask here first. Worst comes to worst I'll try next week and post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. The reason being that your trials passage card can only be used with one boon of each type.

So basically, the best you can get is to skip your first loss, start with a free win, and hopefully get a two for one win on your first match. But after that, you are spent. The card cannot have any more boons and in order to purchase another boon you will need to purchase a new card first.

Comment: That's what I had figured. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @twobugs - It's not a bad idea though :) I am sure there are many people who would be happy if it worked like that.